# How to know what is super key?

Tags: xmodmap, super-key

I have this output of `xmodmap` command:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Caps_Lock (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

So I wonder what's super key here? Problem is that when I try to map super key, here I assume `mod4` as `windows button left` to a combine key using `sxhkd` daemon, it doesn't seem to work, for example, map to open `firefox`, no effect.

EDIT: I'm trying to use `windows left button` on the keyboard to quick map some command using `sxhkd` daemon on archlinux, as discussed in comment, even though I had `keycod 133 mod4 = Super_L` in `.Xmodmap`, using `mod4` in `.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc` to map for example to open firefox:

```
mod4 + f
   firefox
```

this seems doesn't work, press `windows lef button` and `f` didn't invoke firefox or me, just print out series of `ffffff` in terminal.

Answer (score 6):

In response to your first question "I wonder what's super key here": `xmodmap` can't tell what is the key code is, you have to use the command `xev`, check [xev man](http://www.agr.unideb.hu/~agocs/informatics/11_e_unix/unixhelp/unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi1063.html?xev%201) for more information.

Call `xev` from terminal, then click the "super key", after then check the output information in terminal. It will be something like this:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x75, subw 0x0, time 2014984514, (70,-18), root:(82,60),
    state 0x50, keycode 115 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

`xev` tends to generate a lot of output, especially when you move your mouse over terminal window. You may have to scroll back a while to find the output you're looking for. In the previous output, we see that the super_L has keycode 115.

To check the keyboard mapping, the utility `xmodmap` can be used for that purpose. Call `xmodmap` from terminal`, this will print virtual or abstract modifiers (or mod) similar to the table provided in your question.

Tutorial:

In the table provided int eh question text, it seems that `mod3` is not in use. Windows super key is mapped in `mod4` and Hyper_R (or F8) is not mapped at all.

Let's say we would like to map `Hyper_R` to `mod3`. We do the following:

- Call `xev` from terminal >> press `Hyper_R`. This will show the following:

  KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
      root 0x75, subw 0x0, time 2188213888, (74,-12), root:(687,178),
      state 0x10, keycode 74 (keysym 0xffc5, F8), same_screen YES,
      XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XFilterEvent returns: False
- Open `gedit` and type the following:

  clear mod3
  keycode 74 = Hyper_R
  add mod3 =Hyper_R
- Save this information as a hidden file in your home directory. Name the file `.Xmodmap`.
- Log out, then in. After then open terminal and call `xmodmap`. You must see mod3 maped Hyper_R, and so on for any other mapping purposes. For more complicated mapping purposes you may consider some other tools might be more helpful, see [here](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_keyboard_tools.html)

Keep in mind:

`xmodmap` cannot set a key to type key combinations such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

`xmodmap` cannot set a key to run a script.

`xmodmap` key cannot change key based on which is current app.

Comment: You can have `xev` mask events and only display keyboard events with `-event keyboard`. Although even then you get some synthetic keyboard events.

Comment: So that after do this command `xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap` I have to edit `~/.Xmodmap` to add a line like `keycode 115 = Super_L`?

Comment: @TuyenPham exactly, you got it :-)

Comment: Unfortunally, I tried but didn't work, I have like `keycode 133 = Super_L` already when do the command `xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap` but when I try to map using name `super` or `mod4`, `sxhkd` didn't understand.

Comment: Hello @Tuyen Pham,  I am happy to assist on this issue. I understood from your question that you are looking for the code of the suppr key. I would suggest that you make additional edits on the question to clarify what is the problem and I am very happy to help you find a solution ;-)

Comment: I've just add EDIT with the details about problems.

Comment: Almost there, when export to `~/.Xmodmap` I have definition `keycode 133 = Super_L`. Now when I try to map `mod3` as not defined to `keycode 133` by uncomment all definition that contain `Super_L` then add this line in `~/.Xmodmap`: `clear mod3 keycode 133 = Super_L add mod3 = Super_L` and try `xmodmap` in terminal, still showing `mod3` as not defined (I did restart X)